# How to use align environment inside a node in tikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, align

I want 2 aligned environments to sit side by side. I tried `tikZ` package for that (because I know only that, I am a beginner.)

Here's what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0, 0) {\begin{align*} x^2 - y^2 = (x + y) (x - y) \end{align*}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But this raises:

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.8 ...*} x^2 - y^2 = (x + y) (x - y) \end{align*}};
```

What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest not to use `tikz` if your only goal is to have math or text side by side.

- You can put minipages side by side and put everything into it that you can put on a page.

  ```
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
  \begin{align*} x^2 - y^2 = (x + y) (x - y) \end{align*}
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
  \begin{align*} x^2 - y^2 = (x + y) (x - y) \end{align*}
  \end{minipage}
  ```
- You can arrange text and math within `tabular`, `array`, `align`, ... environments.

  ```
  \begin{align*}
  x^2 - y^2 = (x + y) (x - y) &&
  x^2 - y^2 = (x + y) (x - y)
  \end{align*}
  ```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{align*} x^2 - y^2 = (x + y) (x - y) \end{align*}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{align*} x^2 - y^2 = (x + y) (x - y) \end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\begin{align*}
x^2 - y^2 = (x + y) (x - y) &&
x^2 - y^2 = (x + y) (x - y)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for disturbing, I just wanted to ask how could I get 3 minipages side by side?

Comment: @BookOfFlames In the same way you get two minipages side by side: Write them below each other, *without* intervening empty lines (=`\par`). You can separate them by stretchable space (`\hfill`) or fixed space (like `\quad`). If the minipages do not end up in the same line, then their total width (including the space inbetween) is too wide for the page, so the line is wrapped. In this case you have to make them smaller, or the text area wider.

Answer (score 6):

For `align` and the like you need to specify the `text width` (or use another method to set the width), but you can also work with `aligned`, for which you do not need to specify the width.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [text width=5cm] at (0, 0) {\begin{align*} x^2 - y^2 = (x + y) (x - y) \end{align*}};
\node at (0, -2) {$\begin{aligned} x^2 - y^2 &= (x + y) (x - y)\\
a^2+b^2&=c^2 \end{aligned}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]